# OCommandSQLParsingException: No function with name 'gremlin' when sending query from java code to orientdb server

Tags: java, orientdb, gremlin

I'm using `OrientDB v. 3.0.4`, and having a problem trying to send query like

```
String query = new StringBuilder().append("select expand(gremlin(\"")
```

through raw graph:

```
getGraphFactory().getNoTx().getRawGraph().query(new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>(query), ...)
```

I have a following exception on OrientDB side and returned to java server:

> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: No function with name 'gremlin', available names are :
>
> [math_toradians,math_subtractexact,math_asin,st_geomfromtext,math_tanh,math_cbrt,shortestpath,math_ieeeremainder,st_srid,symmetricdifference,traversedvertex,if,indexkeysize,math_tan,unionall,math_cos,in,coalesce,concat,math_cosh,math_nextafter,percentile,math_scalb,difference,document,math_floormod,math_sqrt,sum,st_within,out,math_abs,st_distance_sphere,math_tointexact,min,math_pow,search_more,traversededge,math_max,math_getexponent,map,math_todegrees,set,max,math_log10,math_min,search_index,abs,math_ceil,math_log,math_nextup,st_intersects,math_signum,st_dwithin,first,math_hypot,date,encode,search_fields,dijkstra,st_distance,traversedelement,decode,bothv,st_asbinary,uuid,math_nextdown,mode,sysdate,math_decrementexact,math_exp,search_class,bothe,st_equals,last,math_rint,st_envelope,math_floor,count,format,math_log1p,st_contains,list,both,sequence,st_geomfromgeojson,eval,median,st_astext,decimal,astar,distance,distinct,st_disjoint,math_round,st_buffer,math_copysign,avg,math_sin,math_floordiv,math_sinh,ifnull,stddev,outv,math_multiplyexact,math_atan,ine,oute,intersect,math_incrementexact,st_asgeojson,math_random,math_expm1,inv,variance,math_acos,math_atan2,math_negateexact,math_addexact,math_ulp]`

It seems like function `gremlin` is not registered, or something like that.

Please, advice.

Comment: What version of orientdb? Doesn't it depend on which orientdb version and distribution you use as to whether you get gremlin embedded?